# Nested jQuery accordion for updating multiple forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, accordion

I have a section of div in my page for adding multiple forms and updating it. So in one of the section (tab) I want that it should be nested like

For example: tabs under tab. On click of tab, nested tab should open.

For the above functionality I took [the logic from here](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/) which was easy and simple till it was not nested.

How can I write the nested part so that I can add up to 4-5 nested tabs inside one of my `divs`?

```js
$(function() {
      $("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<div id="accordion">
    <h3 style="text-align: left;">SITE DETAILS</h3>
    <div>
      <span>SITE TYPE: </span>
      <select id="ddlSiteType">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="INDOOR">INDOOR</option>
                    <option value="OUTDOOR">OUTDOOR</option>
                </select>

      <br />
      <span>FACILITY TYPE: </span>
      <select id="ddlFacilityType">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="BTS">BTS</option>
                    <option value="MWR">MWR</option>
                    <option value="OR">OR</option>
                    <option value="FSR">FSR</option>
                    <option value="POI">POI</option>
                    <option value="MAN">MAN</option>
                    <option value="BAN">BAN</option>
                    <option value="MCN">MCN</option>
                    <option value="MSC">MSC</option>
                    <option value="IS">IS</option>
                </select>
      <br />

      <span>PLOT/ROOF TOP AREA ACQUIRED(METER X METER): </span>
      <input type="text" id="txtAreaRequired" />
      <br />

      <span>SITE LOCATION: </span>
      <select id="ddlSiteLocation">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="LOW LYING">LOW LYING</option>
                    <option value="INSIDE FARM">INSIDE FARM</option>
                    <option value="THROUGH OWNERS HOUSE">THROUGH OWNERS HOUSE</option>
                </select>
      <br />

      <span>RJIL SHARING TYPE: </span>
      <select id="ddlRJILSharingType">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="INDOOR">INDOOR</option>
                    <option value="ODC">ODC</option>
                    <option value="RJIL NOT SHARING">RJIL NOT SHARING</option>
                </select>
      <br />

      <span>SITE REACHABILITY /ACCESS: </span>
      <select id="ddlSiteReachabilityAccess">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="ACCESSIBLE BY ROAD">ACCESSIBLE BY ROAD</option>
                    <option value="NOT ACCESSIBLE">NOT ACCESSIBLE</option>
                </select>
      <br />

      <span>GUARDED SITE</span>
      <select id="ddlGuardedSite">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="YES">YES</option>
                    <option value="NO">NO</option>
                </select>
      <br />
      <br />


      <input type="button" id="btnSiteDetails" value="Update Site Details" onclick="return SaveSiteDetails();" />

    </div>



    <h3 style="text-align: left;">TOWER DETAILS</h3>
    <div>
      <span>TOWER TYPE</span>
      <select id="ddlTowerType">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="GBT">GBT</option>
                    <option value="RTT">RTT</option>
                    <option value="RTP">RTP</option>
                </select>
      <br />


      <span>HEIGHT OF TOWER</span>
      <input type="text" id="txtTowerHeight" />
      <br />

      <span>PHYSICAL CONDITION OF TOWER</span>
      <select id="ddlPhysicalCondTower">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="OK">OK</option>
                    <option value="NOT-OK">NOT-OK</option>
                </select>
      <br />


      <span>NO. OF ANGLES MISSING</span>
      <input type="text" id="txtNoOfAnglesMissing" />
      <br />

      <span>NO. OF BRACINGS MISSING</span>
      <input type="text" id="txtNoOfBracingMissing" />
      <br />

      <span>NO. OF CLIT PLATES MISSING</span>
      <input type="text" id="txtNoClitMissing" />
      <br />

      <span>NO OF NUTBOLT MISSING</span>
      <input type="text" id="txtNoOfNutBoltMissing" />
      <br />

      <span>NO OF VACANT GSM MOUNT AVAILABLE AT TOWER</span>
      <input type="text" id="txtNoOfVacantGSMMount" />
      <br />

      <span>NO OF VACANT MW MOUNT AVAILABLE AT TOWER</span>
      <input type="text" id="txtNoOfVacantMWMount" />
      <br />

      <span>TOWER CLIMBING LADDER IN GOOD CONDITION</span>
      <select id="ddlTowerClimbLadderGoodCond">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="YES">YES</option>
                    <option value="NO">NO</option>
                </select>

      <br />
      <br />
                
          
          //Nested code
          
                 <div>
                <span>TOWER TYPE</span>
                <select id="ddlTowerType2">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="GBT">GBT</option>
                    <option value="RTT">RTT</option>
                    <option value="RTP">RTP</option>
                </select>
                <br />


                <span>HEIGHT OF TOWER</span>
                <input type="text" id="txtTowerHeight2" />
                <br />

                <span>PHYSICAL CONDITION OF TOWER</span>
                <select id="ddlPhysicalCondTower2">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="OK">OK</option>
                    <option value="NOT-OK">NOT-OK</option>
                </select>
                <br />


                <span>NO. OF ANGLES MISSING</span>
                <input type="text" id="txtNoOfAnglesMissing2" />
                <br />

                <span>NO. OF BRACINGS MISSING</span>
                <input type="text" id="txtNoOfBracingMissing2" />
                <br />

                <span>NO. OF CLIT PLATES MISSING</span>
                <input type="text" id="txtNoClitMissing2" />
                <br />

                <span>NO OF NUTBOLT MISSING</span>
                <input type="text" id="txtNoOfNutBoltMissing2" />
                <br />

                <span>NO OF VACANT GSM MOUNT AVAILABLE AT TOWER</span>
                <input type="text" id="txtNoOfVacantGSMMount2" />
                <br />

                <span>NO OF VACANT MW MOUNT AVAILABLE AT TOWER</span>
                <input type="text" id="txtNoOfVacantMWMount2" />
                <br />

                <span>TOWER CLIMBING LADDER IN GOOD CONDITION</span>
                <select id="ddlTowerClimbLadderGoodCond2">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="YES">YES</option>
                    <option value="NO">NO</option>
                </select>

                <br />
                <br />

                <input type="button" id="btnTowerDetails" value="Update Tower Details" onclick="return SaveTowerDetails();" />

            </div>
```

Comment: I tried to make you a [mcve] - please complete it

Comment: @mplungjan: sorry for mishaps. updated as much I can. Please help if possible

Comment: Where is `#accordion` element in your `html` ?

Comment: @Pedram: sorry, updated the html now.have a look

Comment: I read your question 3 times, But still not figured out what is your problem, Clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: @Pedram: See, currently u can see 2 tabs which is accordion. Now what I want is, I want to implement nested accordion in one of my tabs like. For ex: whenever a user clicks on Site details tab, then one more tab inside the site details tab should get open with accordion. Did u got it now ?? or should u want some link  ?

Comment: Now we have something.. all you want is add another accordion inside the current accordion. Let me check.

Comment: @Pedram: yes, exactly that is what I want..

Comment: @mplungjan: tried but it was getting too complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your `#accordion` id to `.accordion` class but I recommend you for avoid break your style or script use a `data` attribute for `parent` and `children` accordions. So:

```js
$(function() {
  $("[data-type='accordion']").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
  });
});
```

```css
#accordion2 .ui-accordion-content {
min-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<div id="accordion" data-type="accordion">


  <h3 style="text-align: left;">SITE DETAILS</h3>
  <div>

    <div id="accordion2" data-type="accordion">
      <h3>NEW Content</h3>
      <div> <span>SITE TYPE: </span>
    <select id="ddlSiteType">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="INDOOR">INDOOR</option>
                    <option value="OUTDOOR">OUTDOOR</option>
                </select>

    <br />
    <span>FACILITY TYPE: </span>
    <select id="ddlFacilityType">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="BTS">BTS</option>
                    <option value="MWR">MWR</option>
                    <option value="OR">OR</option>
                    <option value="FSR">FSR</option>
                    <option value="POI">POI</option>
                    <option value="MAN">MAN</option>
                    <option value="BAN">BAN</option>
                    <option value="MCN">MCN</option>
                    <option value="MSC">MSC</option>
                    <option value="IS">IS</option>
                </select>
    <br />

    <span>PLOT/ROOF TOP AREA ACQUIRED(METER X METER): </span>
    <input type="text" id="txtAreaRequired" />
    <br />

    <span>SITE LOCATION: </span>
    <select id="ddlSiteLocation">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="LOW LYING">LOW LYING</option>
                    <option value="INSIDE FARM">INSIDE FARM</option>
                    <option value="THROUGH OWNERS HOUSE">THROUGH OWNERS HOUSE</option>
                </select>
    <br />

    <span>RJIL SHARING TYPE: </span>
    <select id="ddlRJILSharingType">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="INDOOR">INDOOR</option>
                    <option value="ODC">ODC</option>
                    <option value="RJIL NOT SHARING">RJIL NOT SHARING</option>
                </select>
    <br />

    <span>SITE REACHABILITY /ACCESS: </span>
    <select id="ddlSiteReachabilityAccess">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="ACCESSIBLE BY ROAD">ACCESSIBLE BY ROAD</option>
                    <option value="NOT ACCESSIBLE">NOT ACCESSIBLE</option>
                </select>
    <br />

    <span>GUARDED SITE</span>
    <select id="ddlGuardedSite">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="YES">YES</option>
                    <option value="NO">NO</option>
                </select>
    <br />
    <br />


    <input type="button" id="btnSiteDetails" value="Update Site Details" onclick="return SaveSiteDetails();" /></div>
    </div>

    <span>SITE TYPE: </span>
    <select id="ddlSiteType">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="INDOOR">INDOOR</option>
                    <option value="OUTDOOR">OUTDOOR</option>
                </select>

    <br />
    <span>FACILITY TYPE: </span>
    <select id="ddlFacilityType">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="BTS">BTS</option>
                    <option value="MWR">MWR</option>
                    <option value="OR">OR</option>
                    <option value="FSR">FSR</option>
                    <option value="POI">POI</option>
                    <option value="MAN">MAN</option>
                    <option value="BAN">BAN</option>
                    <option value="MCN">MCN</option>
                    <option value="MSC">MSC</option>
                    <option value="IS">IS</option>
                </select>
    <br />

    <span>PLOT/ROOF TOP AREA ACQUIRED(METER X METER): </span>
    <input type="text" id="txtAreaRequired" />
    <br />

    <span>SITE LOCATION: </span>
    <select id="ddlSiteLocation">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="LOW LYING">LOW LYING</option>
                    <option value="INSIDE FARM">INSIDE FARM</option>
                    <option value="THROUGH OWNERS HOUSE">THROUGH OWNERS HOUSE</option>
                </select>
    <br />

    <span>RJIL SHARING TYPE: </span>
    <select id="ddlRJILSharingType">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="INDOOR">INDOOR</option>
                    <option value="ODC">ODC</option>
                    <option value="RJIL NOT SHARING">RJIL NOT SHARING</option>
                </select>
    <br />

    <span>SITE REACHABILITY /ACCESS: </span>
    <select id="ddlSiteReachabilityAccess">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="ACCESSIBLE BY ROAD">ACCESSIBLE BY ROAD</option>
                    <option value="NOT ACCESSIBLE">NOT ACCESSIBLE</option>
                </select>
    <br />

    <span>GUARDED SITE</span>
    <select id="ddlGuardedSite">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="YES">YES</option>
                    <option value="NO">NO</option>
                </select>
    <br />
    <br />


    <input type="button" id="btnSiteDetails" value="Update Site Details" onclick="return SaveSiteDetails();" />

  </div>



  <h3 style="text-align: left;">TOWER DETAILS</h3>
  <div>
    <span>TOWER TYPE</span>
    <select id="ddlTowerType">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="GBT">GBT</option>
                    <option value="RTT">RTT</option>
                    <option value="RTP">RTP</option>
                </select>
    <br />


    <span>HEIGHT OF TOWER</span>
    <input type="text" id="txtTowerHeight" />
    <br />

    <span>PHYSICAL CONDITION OF TOWER</span>
    <select id="ddlPhysicalCondTower">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="OK">OK</option>
                    <option value="NOT-OK">NOT-OK</option>
                </select>
    <br />


    <span>NO. OF ANGLES MISSING</span>
    <input type="text" id="txtNoOfAnglesMissing" />
    <br />

    <span>NO. OF BRACINGS MISSING</span>
    <input type="text" id="txtNoOfBracingMissing" />
    <br />

    <span>NO. OF CLIT PLATES MISSING</span>
    <input type="text" id="txtNoClitMissing" />
    <br />

    <span>NO OF NUTBOLT MISSING</span>
    <input type="text" id="txtNoOfNutBoltMissing" />
    <br />

    <span>NO OF VACANT GSM MOUNT AVAILABLE AT TOWER</span>
    <input type="text" id="txtNoOfVacantGSMMount" />
    <br />

    <span>NO OF VACANT MW MOUNT AVAILABLE AT TOWER</span>
    <input type="text" id="txtNoOfVacantMWMount" />
    <br />

    <span>TOWER CLIMBING LADDER IN GOOD CONDITION</span>
    <select id="ddlTowerClimbLadderGoodCond">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="YES">YES</option>
                    <option value="NO">NO</option>
                </select>

    <br />
    <br /> //Nested code

    <div>
      <span>TOWER TYPE</span>
      <select id="ddlTowerType2">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="GBT">GBT</option>
                    <option value="RTT">RTT</option>
                    <option value="RTP">RTP</option>
                </select>
      <br />


      <span>HEIGHT OF TOWER</span>
      <input type="text" id="txtTowerHeight2" />
      <br />

      <span>PHYSICAL CONDITION OF TOWER</span>
      <select id="ddlPhysicalCondTower2">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="OK">OK</option>
                    <option value="NOT-OK">NOT-OK</option>
                </select>
      <br />


      <span>NO. OF ANGLES MISSING</span>
      <input type="text" id="txtNoOfAnglesMissing2" />
      <br />

      <span>NO. OF BRACINGS MISSING</span>
      <input type="text" id="txtNoOfBracingMissing2" />
      <br />

      <span>NO. OF CLIT PLATES MISSING</span>
      <input type="text" id="txtNoClitMissing2" />
      <br />

      <span>NO OF NUTBOLT MISSING</span>
      <input type="text" id="txtNoOfNutBoltMissing2" />
      <br />

      <span>NO OF VACANT GSM MOUNT AVAILABLE AT TOWER</span>
      <input type="text" id="txtNoOfVacantGSMMount2" />
      <br />

      <span>NO OF VACANT MW MOUNT AVAILABLE AT TOWER</span>
      <input type="text" id="txtNoOfVacantMWMount2" />
      <br />

      <span>TOWER CLIMBING LADDER IN GOOD CONDITION</span>
      <select id="ddlTowerClimbLadderGoodCond2">
                    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="YES">YES</option>
                    <option value="NO">NO</option>
                </select>

      <br />
      <br />

      <input type="button" id="btnTowerDetails" value="Update Tower Details" onclick="return SaveTowerDetails();" />

    </div>
```

But if styles does not matter, use this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
  });
});
```

Comment: If I am adding the same html in place of `hello` its not working

Comment: same html as parent? @BNN

Comment: I guess, i need to take each section inside div.. right ?

Comment: @BNN Kinda yes. See updated answer, but you need to set bigger height for nested one. But be aware you need to change copied content's ID to class to avoid duplicate ID.

Comment: yes, currently height is giving me the severe issue

Comment: what extra did u added to maintain height ??

Comment: @BNN What do you mean? I just set `min-height`

Comment: yes got it, how to define for mutiple accordion. i mean something like this is not working `#accordion1, #accordion2 .ui-accordion-content {
            min-height: 300px;
        }`

Comment: This selector => `#accordion1 .ui-accordion-content, #accordion2 .ui-accordion-content { min-height: 300px;}` @BNN